# Importing bootstrap.css,unknown CSS classes showing up

Tags: css

I have a page with imported CSS on it like this :

```
<style type="text/css">
    @import url('css/common.css');      
</style>
```

When using a PDF generation function, I used alert debugging to check the style :

```
alert('style: ' +document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0].innerHTML);
```

alert shows this :

```
style: 
    .xn0 { color:#010101;font-family:Lucida Grande, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;}
    .xn1 { color:#010101;font-family:Lucida Grande, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;}
    .xn2 { color:#999999;font-family:Lucida Grande, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;}
    .xnb { color:#010101;font-family:Lucida Grande, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;}
    .if2 { color:#010101;font-family:Lucida Grande, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;border:0px;border-bottom:1px dotted #CFCFCF;width:100%;}
```

I dont know where these classes are getting into my page from, please help ....

Comment: can you put your codes in fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was garbage collection comming from the css which is of no use it does not effect my page so just simply ignore it ...

Answer (score -1):

You can overwrite those properties with `!important`, like this:

Original:

```
.xn0 { color:#010101; }
```

Overwrite:

```
.xn0 { color:white !important; }
```

Note: Make shure your custom css is imported after:

```
<style type="text/css">
   @import url('css/common.css');
   @import url('css/your_custom_code.css');      
</style>
```

Hope it works!

Comment: No it does not work ... i dont wont xn0 class and dont even from where it is comming ...